# temporarily take ownership of a folder

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, powershell-4.0

I need to temporarily take ownership of a profilefolder, in order to add permissions(ReadOnly) to members of a securitygroup. I would like to know how to achieve this in powershell.

I have before used `TakeOwn.exe`, but since it can't give ownership back to the original owner, I can't use it for this.

I tried using a module called `PowerShellAccessControl`, which I found on [technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/c7928ef1-e745-4f03-93a8-5c198b811d07/temporarily-take-ownership-of-folders-to-set-permissions?forum=winserverpowershell).

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\modules\PowerShellAccessControl\PowerShellAccessControl.psd1

$path = "$PSScriptRoot\profileFolders\profile"

$AddAceParams = @{
    Principal = "SecurityGroup"
    FolderRights = "Read"
}

Get-SecurityDescriptor $path -PacSDOption (New-PacCommandOption -BypassAclCheck) | ForEach-Object {
    $OriginalOwner = $_.Owner

    $_ | Set-Owner -PassThru -Apply | 
        Add-AccessControlEntry @AddAceParams -PassThru |
        Set-Owner -Principal $OriginalOwner -Apply 
}
```

But this code only resultet in the following error:

> New-PacCommandOption : The term 'New-PacCommandOption' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I dont know if i should continue with this module or if there is a better way.

Comment: You need to install [the module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShellAccessControl-d3be7b83) linked in the answer on TechNet to make this script working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use the [NTFSSecurity](https://github.com/raandree/NTFSSecurity) module when dealing with filesystem permissions, it's well written and I've had good success with it so far.

```
$path = "C:\folder"
$OriginalPermissions = Get-NTFSOwner $path

Set-NTFSOwner -Path $path -Account $env:USERNAME
Add-NTFSAccess -Path $path -Account 'DOMAIN\SecurityGroup' -AccessRights Read
Set-NTFSOwner -Path $path -Account $OriginalPermissions.Owner
```

Note: You do need to install the module, if you're using a modern version of Powershell this is easy as you can just use `Install-Module -Name NTFSSecurity`. If it's an older version you will need download and install the module manually.

---

EDIT:

The other option is to use `Enable-Privileges` to grant your account the privileges for `Backup, Restore, and Security`.

With these you will be able to edit the permissions without your own account having explicit permissions to the data. Use of these command is covered in the documentation in the link above. Be sure to `Disable-Privileges` after enabling them as it's not good practice to run with these all the time.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. I noticed that there isn't  a -Recurse option for Set-NTFSOwner and Add-NTFSAccess. Is this the best workaround: 

`dir2 $path -Recurse | Set-NTFSOwner -Account $env:USERNAME

dir2 $path -Recurse | Add-NTFSAccess -Account $securityGroup -AccessRights Read

dir2 $path -Recurse | Set-NTFSOwner -Account $OriginalPermissions.Owner`